# Invalidate all cache entries for a paginated list query in in Apollo GraphQL

Tags: graphql, pagination, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a paginated, sortable, filterable list. If I understand Apollos Cache correctly, it stores a cache entry for each combination of sorting and filtering. When I now add an item to the list, I need to invalidate all these cache entries since the order or filter result might have changed.

When adding the item, I can `refetch` the list items query (`getItems`) in the `addItem` mutation, but the cache will only be reset for the default sorting case. I probably would need to refetch the `getItems` query with each possible sorting, but that feels wrong. My current workaround is just overriding the cache by setting the network policy to `no-cache`, but that is not my preferred solution.

Some code:
my query to load the list items:

```
const { loading, error, data, fetchMore } = useQuery<
        Items
        ItemsVariables
    >(getItems, {
        variables: {
            filters: {
                ...props.filters,
            },
            offset: 0,
            limit: 5,
            sorting: props.sortingSettings,
        },
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    })
```

my mutation triggering a refetch

```
createItemMutation({
            variables: {
                // title and stuff about the listItem,
            },
            refetchQueries: [
                {
                    query: getItems.query,
                },
            ],
```

Is there a way to refetch all "variations" of this query?
Im using the apollo client v3 in a react application and a kotlin / spring boot backend.

I've tried refetching, searched the apollo pagination docs, found out that I could reset the whole cache but that sounds a bit overkill since I would also lose other cached data.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: @David Sadly not. We're still using the `network-only` fetch policy.